# how to disprove uniform convergence

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I've been asked to check the uniform convergence of the following function sequence on the real line:
$$
f_{N}(t)=\sum_{n=-N}^{n=N}\sin(n) \,\frac{\sin(\pi t-\pi n)}{\pi t-\pi n}
$$
It is asked in a course of Fourier Analysis.
I've managed to prove it converges pointiwse to $ \sin(t) $ using the fourier series of  $\sin(tx)$ and substituting $x=1$.

However,  I have failed to prove/disprove uniform convergence.
Using wolfram alpha I could see it does not uniformly converge. 
I took $N=20$ and $ x=20\pi + \pi /2 $, and the sum turned out to be roughly zero where it should have been roughly $1$.

Comment: Sequence of functions tends to $f$ uniformly if $\sup |f_N(x)-f(x)| \to 0$. If you can calculate this supremum explicitly as a function of $N$, you will be done.

Comment: The problem is I have not been able to calculate this :(

Comment: I assume that if t is an integer and N is at least abs(t) then you take the term with n=t to have the value sin(n) (which is sin(t) ).

Answer (score 0):

[1] I assume that the term in which $t=n$,if it exists, equals $\sin t$...[2] Observe that $\sin (\pi t- \pi n)=(-1)^n \sin \pi t$ for integer $n$...[3] Assume uniform convergence. Then for some $N > |t|$ we have $|f_{N+1}(t)-f_N(t)| < 1/2$ for all $t$. But for $N>|t|$, we have $|f_{N+1}(t)-f_N(t)|=|[(2N+2) \sin \pi t ]/[\pi (t^2-(N+1)^2]|$ which for $t=N+1+d \ne N+1$ is  $| [\sin \pi d)/ \pi d].[(2N+2)/(2N+2+d)]|$ which is arbitrarily close to $1$ if $|d|$ is small enough.Contradiction, so convergence is not uniform. (Question: Is convergence uniform on every bounded set? I dk.)

Comment: Thanks for the response!
But could it be that you forgot the sin(n) term in the sum?

Comment: i edited my answer to restrict N to N>|t|